# How to dynamic create django form with the same "name=" attr for each field?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-models

I need to create django form with checkbox fields. Number of fields and value of "checked" attribute are dynamic.

I created form:

```
form = DynamicForm()
for field in all_fields:
    if field in checked_field:
        form.fields[field.id]=forms.BooleanField(label=field.name, initial=True)
    else:
        form.fields[field.id]=forms.BooleanField(label=field.name, initial=False)
return form
```

,but this form has different value of "name" attribute for each field (name=field.id). 
 How to set the same name for every field?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to do something wrong :) What's the final purpose of having the same name attribute for each checkbox?

Comment: I want to get POST data from this form in a list, ex.: checked_fields = request.POST.getlist("same_name_attr")

Comment: ex.2: http://www.djangofoo.com/93/request-post-get-multiple-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't do with multiple BooleanFields. You do it with a single [`MultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield), which is output as a series of checkboxes with the same name.